# get each div id in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a for loop based on divs count I need to select each div child so I got to get the id of the div.

this is what I have tried:

```js
var json = [{
  'orderId': order,
  'attributes': [],
  'services': []
}];
var divLength = $('#stepchild div').length;
for (i = 0; i < divLength; i++) {
  var fields = {};
  $('#divID input').each(function() {
    fields[this.name] = $(this).val();
  })
  $('#divID select').each(function() {
    fields[this.name] = $(this).val();
  })
  json[0]['attributes'].push(fields);
}
```

```html
<div id="form0">
  <input type="text" class="field1">
</div>
<div id="form1">
  <input type="text" class="field1">
</div>
<div id="form2">
  <input type="text" class="field1">
</div>
```

Comment: Provide your html code as well

Comment: i guess you ask about how to get id for each div, right?

Answer (score 3):

#### Disclaimer : I know the question is about jquery, but I would like to provide the non-jQuery version :

If you just want the IDs in a list, you can use this :

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].map(div => div.id)
```

Or if you need to loop over them and do some processing for each, you can use this :

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(div => {
    // process the div element here with div.id beeing the ID
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop like this (basic example):

```
$('div').each(function()
{
    console.log($(this).attr('id'))
})
```

refs:

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('target').each(function()
{
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

this will run for each target match .  in your case 'div' is your target . you can use find , child  attribute for sub search

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow

You need to use `map` function here in order to collect ID or value inside the textbox.

Here is an example to get ID:

```js
var json = [{
    'orderId': 'order',
    'attributes': [],
    'services': []
}];

function getDivID() 
{
            
    var values = $("#stepchild div").map(function (i, e) {
        return $(e).attr('id');
    }).get();


    json[0]['attributes'].push(values);

    console.log("json[0]['attributes'] is now : " + json[0]['attributes']);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="stepchild">
    <div id="form0">
        <input type="text" class="field1">
    </div>
    <div id="form1">
        <input type="text" class="field1">
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
        <input type="text" class="field1">
    </div>
</div>

<button onclick="getDivID()">Click here to get div ID</button>
```

Using `.map()` function you can also collect value form each element inside div :

```js
var json = [{
    'orderId': 'order',
    'attributes': [],
    'services': []
}];


function getValue() {

    var values = $("#stepchild input").map(function (i, e) {
        return $(e).val();
    }).get();


    json[0]['attributes'].push(values);

    console.log("json[0]['attributes'] is now : " + json[0]['attributes']);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="stepchild">
    <div id="form0">
        <input type="text" class="field1" value="abc">
    </div>
    <div id="form1">
        <input type="text" class="field1" value="xyz">
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
        <input type="text" class="field1" value="something">
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="getValue()">Click here to get value</button>
```

refs: 
http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1):

Within `$.fn.each`, you can access the current element id with `this.id` or with the parameter `element.id`.

Keep in mind that `$()` will give you a collection. You can write your code like this:

```js
const json = [{
  'orderId': order,
  'attributes': [],
  'services': [],
}];

$('#stepchild div').each(function (index, element) {
  let fields = {};
  
  $(element).find('input, select').each(function () {
    fields[this.name] = $(this).val();
  });
  
  json[0]['attributes'].push(fields);
});
```